# network image showing in flutter web but not showing in mobile flutter

Tags: android, flutter, image, android-emulator

When i run flutter in web with command

> flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html --no-sound-null-safety

Network Image show in flutter web but when i run in mobile it not show 3

Error :

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403, https://shop.znindia.com/public/uploads/all/a4llgBQ6ExlDcp94FeFFhkJyFEqQsCyi88EDAl5D9CEvBt4nPa.jpg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:117:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://shop.znindia.com/public/uploads/all/a4llgBQ6ExlDcp94FeFFhkJyFEqQsCyi88EDAl5D9CEvBt4nPa.jpg", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://shop.znindia.com/public/uploads/all/a4llgBQ6ExlDcp94FeFFhkJyFEqQsCyi88EDAl5D9CEvBt4nPa.jpg", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

When i open the image url in the browser image shows perfectly.
My image show code is

```
SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
  child: FadeInImage(
    placeholder: const AssetImage("assets/logo.png"),
    image: NetworkImage(
      productImage,
    ),
  ),
),
```

My manifest code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.znindia.stock">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Calling in list view

```
return ProductWidget(
  context,
  productId: products[index][0],
  productImage: products[index][8],
  productName: products[index][1],
  onDeleteOptionClick: () {
    deleteProduct(
      id: products[index][0],
      name: products[index][1],
      categoryId: products[index][2],
      brandId: products[index][3],
      qty: products[index][4],
      purchasePrice: products[index][5],
      salePrice: products[index][6],
      hsnCode: products[index][7],
      image: products[index][8],
      tax: products[index][9],
    );
  },
);
```

and ProductWidget is

```
ProductWidget(context,
    {required int productId,
    required String productImage,
    required String productName,
    required VoidCallback onDeleteOptionClick}) {
  return buildCustomButtonCard(
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
          child: (productImage == "")
              ? Container()
              : SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                  child: Image.network(
                    productImage,
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: have you given your path in pubspac.yaml.

Comment: its network image

Comment: can you add your image url?

Comment: Where and how are you declaring and valuing productImage. Please, show more code.

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil the url is already in error message.

Comment: image url is productImage. productImage = https://shop.znindia.com/public/uploads/all/mf1Ska5QL4SvVpxsnQvyCi4qI2E59l9oG49kJxntscFNuKvlwQ.jpg

Comment: @IshantSingh I test your image it gives `403` **Status Code**

Comment: but image opening in browser and working in flutter web

Comment: Yes correct but it gives the error 403, `HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403, https://shop.znindia.com/public/uploads/all/mf1Ska5QL4SvVpxsnQvyCi4qI2E59l9oG49kJxntscFNuKvlwQ.jpg`

Comment: @IshantSingh I think your image has problem I have try it other way also using [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) but it also give `HttpException: Invalid statusCode: 403, uri = https://shop.znindia.com/public/uploads/all/mf1Ska5QL4SvVpxsnQvyCi4qI2E59l9oG49kJxntscFNuKvlwQ.jpg`

Comment: ok wait i search what is error